# How to use OData metadata for type definition during binding in SAPUI5?

Tags: binding, odata, sapui5

I build a method that allows me to get a data type according to the odata metadata model.

This method works like this:

1. read the metadata from odata service
2. search for the entity type
3. search for the property
4. map the Edm:* to some default value (if possible it uses further metadata information)
5. return the data type

My problem is now, that metadata is loaded asynchronous.

Therefore I register to `attachMetadataLoaded` during startup to ensure the data is loaded if the method is used first time.

This lead to the fact of a blank start up screen for some seconds.

Example of my current solution:

In a view:

```
new sap.m.Input({
  value : {
     path : "/Entity/Property",
     type : Some.Object.getTypeFor("Entity", "Property")
  } 
});
```

The function would work like this:

```
function getTypeFor(sEntity, sProperty) {
   var oMetaData = oModel.getServiceMetadata();
   // search for sEntity and in there for sProperty inside the oMetaData
   var oPropertyMeta = ...
   switch (oPropertyMeta.type) {
     case "Edm:String" :
            var oConstraints = {};
            if (property.maxLength) {
                oConstraints.maxLength = Number(property.maxLength);
            }
        return new sap.ui.model.type.String(null, oConstraints);
     ...
   }
```

Is there a way to wait (inside the function) if metadata is not loaded?
Or a smarter way to get some default type for a binding according to the metadata?

### Edit

I am using the v2.odatamodel, there the metadata will be loaded async.
Looks like the smartfield will also not work correct in that case?

Answer (score 1):

Is there a way to wait (inside the function) if metadata is not loaded?

`oModel.attachMetadataLoaded(fnCallBack);`

On my current project I have a very similar requirement to yours.

We looked at the sap.ui.comp.sample.smartfield @matbtt mentions, it didn't support all the input control types we wanted, multi combo, combo, inputs, segmented buttons etc.

We also looked into [XML Templates](https://ui5.sap.com/#/sample/sap.ui.core.sample.ViewTemplate.types/preview) which worked well, but plays better with OData Annotations than OData Model. And in our version of Gateway the Annotations are still too limiting to be useful (roll on 7.5)

The issue that you might find with your approach, there is more than one use case for EDM.String - think Input / Text / Text Area, all have the same Type, similarly with EDM.Int16 and EDM.Decimal etc. lots of use cases for numbers, different lengths, different decimal places etc.

The solution we ended up with was a Control Factory where we pass in a more specific data Type which maps to a control
eg 
  -

- DATE -> DatePicker
- BUTTON -> Button
- NUMBER -> Input with Number constraints
- CURRENCY -> Input with Number constraints, with add. Currency constraints
- YEAR -> Input with Number constraints, with add. Year constraints

We would have like to have used Annotations for this, but ended up using a separate Entity.

hth

Comment: I used oModel.attachMetadataLoaded(fnCallBack) during start up to ensure metadata is loaded. But I can't use a callback if I use the "type" attribute of a binding property. As mentioned in my post already.

Comment: use a factory function for your new control, by the time the bindingContext is ready the metadata will already be loaded

Answer (score -1):

You can use [SmartField](https://sapui5.netweaver.ondemand.com/explored.html#/entity/sap.ui.comp.smartfield.SmartField/about) to let UI5 do the magic.

Comment: I have two problems with the SmartField. First of seems not fit to sap.m.* layout. Second it is not part of openui5. I prefer to avoid controls not available in openui5. But yes, I am searching for a way that a binding will use a default type based on metadata (but should be possible to override if required).

Comment: Okay, understand. There was no hint that you are using OpenUI5. I fear that you need to enhance the type derivation of the ODataPropertyBinding implementation.

Comment: I am using SAPUI5, and detected now that the SmartField will adapt to the sap.m Layout. Anyhow if I do not wait during app init till metadata is loaded I got the followign error: Assertion failed: No metadata loaded! I always have to register attachMetadataLoaded and wait before I can use metadata (or the SmartField). In the example (SDK) for the field the metadata will be loaded manually. And I am using v2.odatamodel!